# How to add an attribute to an HTML string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the `'selected'` attribute in a select option list with javascript/jquery.  I have the select element in a jquery object, I just want to add the "selected" attribute to and item in the list.

`$(mySelect).html()` looks like this;

```
<option value="LININGER LAKE">LININGER LAKE</option>
<option value="MOOREDALE LAKE">MOOREDALE LAKE</option>
<option value="CARTER LAKE">CARTER LAKE</option>
```

I need to find the "CARTER LAKE" option and add the selected attribute to it so the HTML looks like this

```
<option value="LININGER LAKE">LININGER LAKE</option>
<option value="MOOREDALE LAKE">MOOREDALE LAKE</option>
<option value="CARTER LAKE" selected="selected">CARTER LAKE</option>
```

I know this can't be that hard, I'm just having a brain fart!

Comment: Why not just set the `selectedIndex` or `value` of the containing `<select>` element?

Comment: Can you post a complete code example please? What's `mySelect`?

Comment: Have you tried `$(yourSelectSelector).val('CARTER LAKE')`?

Comment: I was framing this problem wrong, I should not have been digging into the html, just sticking to jquery methods was much easier.  Per Yury Tarabanko answer, setting the .val() on the select element did the trick.  Thanks for all the fast replies and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as `$(mySelect).val('CARTER LAKE')`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s47rkqfu/)

Comment: Duh... I was making this WAY too complicated!!  Thanks for bringing back to earth!

Answer (score 2):

Use the [jQuery Attribute Equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$(mySelect).find('option[value="CARTER LAKE"]').prop("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `.contains()` as shown

```
 $("select option:contains('CARTER LAKE')").attr('selected','selected')
```

OR

```
 $("select option:contains('CARTER LAKE')").prop('selected',true)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o9j72zq6/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('option[value="CARTER LAKE"]').prop( "selected" );
```

or

```
$('option[value="CARTER LAKE"]').attr( "selected", "selected" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
$('option[value="CARTER LAKE"]').attr( "selected", "selected" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="LININGER LAKE">LININGER LAKE</option>
<option value="MOOREDALE LAKE">MOOREDALE LAKE</option>
<option value="CARTER LAKE">CARTER LAKE</option>
  </select>
```